# How to get correct string text?

Tags: c#, encoding, character-encoding, unicode-escapes

I'm trying to obtain the correct unicode characters represented by this string:

```
string originalString = "\u0605\u04c3\u5000\u0000\u5000\ufd00\u4400\ud500\u7600\ud300\u4f00\ubc00\u0c00\u2d00\u4000\ue400\u0e00\u7400\u4800\ub700\u1d00\u1300\ue900\u6000\u4c00\ufb00\u9900\u3900\ud900\u6700\uae00\ueb00\u8f00\u2800\u0200\ub300\u5c00\ufe00\u0100\u3d00\u9100\u3000\u0300\u1600\u0100\u7000\u6200\u8e00\u1d00\u8e00\u6200\ua900\u6300\uc800\u0900\ub700\ub000\u6000\ue400\u9200\u3f00\u9100\u8d00\uef00\u3600\u0100\u9e00\u0081";
```

If I hard-code it in the cs file, I can see in debug mode that it shows the correct characters, but if I have the exact string written in a file and I try to read it, it shows the string as it is in the file.

```
TextReader tr = new StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");
string tmpString = tr.ReadLine();
tr.Close();

byte[] array = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(tmpString );
string finalResult = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(array);
```

How can I make the finalResult string have the correct unicode characters?

Thanks in advance
Gonçalo

**EDIT**: Already tried placing

```
TextReader tr = new StreamReader("c:\\test.txt",Encoding.Unicode);
```

but the characters are different from the correct ones.

Comment: How do you save your text file? You have to make sure what encoding your text file is. E.g. Notepad has an option for determining whether you want to save as Unicode (probably UTF16) or UTF8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your file actually contain the content:

> \u0605\u04c3\u5000\u0000\u5000\ufd00\u4400\ud500\u7600\ud300\u4f00
>   \ubc00\u0c00\u2d00\u4000\ue400\u0e00\u7400\u4800\ub700\u1d00\u1300
>   \ue900\u6000\u4c00\ufb00\u9900\u3900\ud900\u6700\uae00\ueb00\u8f00
>   \u2800\u0200\ub300\u5c00\ufe00\u0100\u3d00\u9100\u3000\u0300\u1600
>   \u0100\u7000\u6200\u8e00\u1d00\u8e00\u6200\ua900\u6300\uc800\u0900
>   \ub700\ub000\u6000\ue400\u9200\u3f00\u9100\u8d00\uef00\u3600\u0100\u9e00\u0081

If so, you need to convert each sequence to its corresponding unicode character

```
    string originalString = "\u0605\u04c3\u5000\u0000\u5000\ufd00\u4400\ud500\u7600\ud300\u4f00\ubc00\u0c00\u2d00\u4000\ue400\u0e00\u7400\u4800\ub700\u1d00\u1300\ue900\u6000\u4c00\ufb00\u9900\u3900\ud900\u6700\uae00\ueb00\u8f00\u2800\u0200\ub300\u5c00\ufe00\u0100\u3d00\u9100\u3000\u0300\u1600\u0100\u7000\u6200\u8e00\u1d00\u8e00\u6200\ua900\u6300\uc800\u0900\ub700\ub000\u6000\ue400\u9200\u3f00\u9100\u8d00\uef00\u3600\u0100\u9e00\u0081";
    string tmpString = "\\u0605\\u04c3\\u5000\\u0000\\u5000\\ufd00\\u4400\\ud500\\u7600\\ud300\\u4f00\\ubc00\\u0c00\\u2d00\\u4000\\ue400\\u0e00\\u7400\\u4800\\ub700\\u1d00\\u1300\\ue900\\u6000\\u4c00\\ufb00\\u9900\\u3900\\ud900\\u6700\\uae00\\ueb00\\u8f00\\u2800\\u0200\\ub300\\u5c00\\ufe00\\u0100\\u3d00\\u9100\\u3000\\u0300\\u1600\\u0100\\u7000\\u6200\\u8e00\\u1d00\\u8e00\\u6200\\ua900\\u6300\\uc800\\u0900\\ub700\\ub000\\u6000\\ue400\\u9200\\u3f00\\u9100\\u8d00\\uef00\\u3600\\u0100\\u9e00\\u0081";

    string finalResult = Regex.Replace(tmpString, @"\\u(....)", match => ((char)int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Encoding as parameter while reading the file

```
   TextReader tr = new StreamReader("c:\\test.txt",Encoding.Unicode);
   string unicode_string = tr.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
TextReader streamReader = new StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");
string input = streamReader.ReadLine();
string[] chars = input.Split(new char[] { '\\', 'u' }, 
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
streamReader.Close();

string answer = string.Empty;
foreach (string charachter in chars)
{
    byte byte1 = byte.Parse(string.Format("{0}{1}", 
        charachter[0], charachter[1]), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
    byte byte2 = byte.Parse(string.Format("{0}{1}", 
        charachter[2], charachter[3]), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
    answer += Encoding.Unicode.GetString(new byte[] { byte2, byte1 });
}
```